# Switch goes through all cases

Tags: javascript

I have the following code. Switch statement goes through all cases, except the default one, even if i have break point.

I tried to declare an array of [0, 1, 2] and to loop through that for the switch cases, but it didn't work.

```
const button = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            let userPick;
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                    userPick = button[i].getAttribute("data-pick");
                    console.log("UserPick: " + userPick);
                    break;
                default:
                    userPick = "Wrong";
                    console.log("UserPick: " + userPick);
                    break;
            }
    
        }
```

What I want to do is to print the value of the button. For example,

for case 0, I want to print "firstButton"
for case 1, "secondButton"  and so on.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: What do you expect to happen instead and why? Your code is equivalent to ``Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".btn")).slice(0, 3).forEach({dataset: {pick}}) => console.log(`UserPick: ${pick}`));``.

Comment: What is it supposed to do? With the way it's written, it should use the first `userPick =` block when `i` is `0`/`1`/`2` and the 2nd one otherwise.

Comment: The `default` case will never be hit, increase 3 to 4 and it will. The default case means "when nothing else is reached, come here instead."

Comment: _“What I want to do is to print the value of the button. For example, for case 0, I want to print ‘firstButton’ for case 1, ‘secondButton’ and so on.”_ — And how does the `switch` not achieve this goal? Why do you even use a `switch` here? Where do the names _“firstButton”_, _“secondButton”_, etc., come from?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `switch` here since you already have a for-loop that goes through all the valid cases (0 to 2). This would be the same as

```js
const button = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const userPick = button[i].getAttribute("data-pick");
    console.log("UserPick: " + userPick);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the comment by Hanlet Escano.  Your loop variable will never be higher than 2, so default will not be hit.  Fix that first, and then see if your code accomplishes what you expect.

Edited:  I'm answering the question that was asked:  why isn't default being hit.  Whatever else the code is intended to do isn't clear.